# Ajax watch database for changes and execute code

Tags: javascript, php, html, httprequest

My goal is to more or less send out requests to a php file, giving it parameters like so;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
<script>
function onsubmit()
{
var id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    window.WhateverVariable = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","clientrequest.php?id="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and keep sending out requests untill my php script returns x value, which will be passed into the window.WhateverVariable, and when the WhateverVariable is equal to 'x' I wish to execute some code;

however, I can achieve this, but when the code is executed, the request is still going meaning the response text will be 'x' and will continuously destroy then re-execute the code, any way to get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( the_mini_game_is_not_open() )
{
    // send the regular ajax request
} else {
    // send the ajax request but with the message that the mini game is open through parameters maybe like ?open=1
}
```

And on server side deal with this like:

```
if ( isset ( $_GET['open'] ) && $_GET['open'] === 1 )
{
   // pause it or whatever...
} else {
   // show the regular results
}
```

This was what I understood. Sorry if that's not what you want

Comment: On the server side, I see that it is recognizing if the game is open via parameters, buy what do you mean pause it or whatever? I wish to keep the game open untill the value 'test' changes to something else, thanks :)

Comment: you can store the value of test in a session and compare it on every request if it changes.

Comment: Thank you! But I have a problem, now that the 'x' has been achieved, and the minigame is open when the requests send and see that the 'x' vlue is achieved it will continuously open new minigames? :(

Comment: on server side you can change the response by checking into that session and when that session has the same value just echo something that will tell the javascript that now is the time to let the user play the game. THe game that is already opened. Not new games. I hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank's I think I now understand how to achieve it :)